# Union Rectangle Calculator

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and have a problem I just can't solve.

> What is the area of the union of two rectangles R1 and R2, where top left
> corner of R1 is (X1,Y1) and its size is (W1,H1), and top left corner of R2
> is (X2,Y2) and its size is (W2,H2)?

```
Please enter X1, Y1, W1, H1, X2, Y2, W2, H2: 0 0 5 10 0 0 10 5
Result: Intersection area is 25 thus the total area of the union is 75.
```

There said that I cannot use math class methods, and I wrote something like this:

```
public static int overlapCalculator(int x1, int y1, int w1, int h1, int x2, int y2, int w2, int h2) {
    int OverlapX = 0;
    int OverlapY = 0;
    
    // Calculate x-axis overlap
    if (x1 < x2 && x1 + w1 > x2) {
        if (x2 + w2 <= x1 + w1) {
            OverlapX = w2;
        } else {
            OverlapX = x1 + w1 - x2;
        }
    } else if (x2 < x1 && x2 + w2 > x1) {
        if (x1 + w1 <= x2 + w2) {
            OverlapX = w1;
        } else {
            OverlapX = x2 + w2 - x1;
        }
    }
    
    // Calculate y-axis overlap
    if (y1 < y2 && y1 + h1 > y2) {
        if (y2 + h2 <= y1 + h1) {
            OverlapY = h2;
        } 
        
        else {
            OverlapY = y1 + h1 - y2;
        }
    } 
    
    else if (y2 < y1 && y2 + h2 > y1) {
        if (y1 + h1 <= y2 + h2) {
            OverlapY = h1;
        } 
        
        else {
            OverlapY = y2 + h2 - y1;
        }
    }
    
    int Area = w1 * h1 + w2 * h2 - OverlapX * OverlapY;
    int overLapArea = Area - w1 * x2;
    
    return overLapArea;
}
```

How can I change it that it shows the union area separately?

1. First, we declare two variables to hold the overlap in the x-axis and y-axis respectively.
2. Next, we calculate the overlap in the x-axis:

   1. We check if the left edge of rectangle 1 is to the left of the left edge of rectangle 2 AND the right edge of rectangle 1 is to the right of the left edge of rectangle 2. If this condition is true, then there is an overlap in the x-axis.
   2. We then check if the right edge of rectangle 2 is entirely contained within rectangle 1. If it is, then the x-axis overlap is simply the width of rectangle 2.
   3. Otherwise, we calculate the width of the overlap as the distance from the left edge of rectangle 2 to the right edge of rectangle 1. We handle the case where rectangle 2 is to the left of rectangle 1 in a similar manner.
3. We calculate the overlap in the y-axis in a similar way.
4. Finally, we calculate the area of the union of the two rectangles by adding the areas of the two rectangles and subtracting the area of the overlap.

I get 100 for the first one where I should get 25 & 75.

Comment: Time to use a debugger, or sprinkle lots of `println` statements throughout your code, to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Looks like that) I think I found another way to calculate it, will post later

Comment: it is like one part of rectangle is in another one, and we need to find the area of that intersection.

Comment: Are you trying to find the smallest rectangle that encloses the two rectangles? If yes, then have you seen [Perimeter of the Union of Two Rectangles](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perimeter-of-the-union-of-two-rectangles/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("- What is the area of the union of two rectangles R1 and R2, where top left corner of R1 is (X1,Y1) and its size is (W1,H1), and top left corner of R2 is (X2,Y2) and its size is (W2,H2)? \n");
    System.out.print("Please enter X1, Y1, W1, H1, X2, Y2, W2, H2: ");
                    
               

 //taking inputs for first rectangle
                int x1 = sc.nextInt();
                int y1 = sc.nextInt();
                int w1 = sc.nextInt();
                int h1 = sc.nextInt();
                
                //taking inputs for the second rectangle
                int x2 = sc.nextInt();
                int y2 = sc.nextInt();
                int w2 = sc.nextInt();
                int h2 = sc.nextInt();



                int answer = overlapCalculator(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2);
                int area1 = w1*h1;
                int area2 = w2*h2;
                int sumArea = area1 + area2;
                int intersectionArea = sumArea - answer;
                System.out.println("Result: Intersection area is " + intersectionArea + " thus the total area of the union is " + answer + ".");
```

Comment: Are you [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? Or should this code be part of your question?